# PowerShell button.add_Click runs each time all the previous clicks

Tags: powershell, button, event-handling

First of all, sorry for the title but I didn't found a better way to summarize the problem.

I have the following code in my gui script:

```
    $Button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
    $Button1.Text = 'Computername' 
    $Button1.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(30,70) 
    $Button1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,65) 
    $Button1.add_Click({
        $Button1.Enabled = $False
        $ConsoleTextbox.Text = cls
        $ConsoleTextbox.AppendText("My text appended")
        $main_form.Controls.Add($OKButton16)
        $main_form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)
        $OKButton16.add_Click({
            $ConsoleTextbox.AppendText("More text appended")
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Mycomputer -Credential $Credentials -ScriptBlock {Restart-Service -Name "*spool*" -Force} -AsJob -JobName JOB1
            $ConsoleTextbox.AppendText("`n")
            $ConsoleTextbox.AppendText("Appending more text")
            $ConsoleTextbox.AppendText("`n")
            $ConsoleTextbox.AppendText("`n")
            $main_form.Controls.Remove($OKButton16)
            $main_form.Controls.Remove($CancelButton)
            $Button1.Enabled = $true
        })
    })
```

When you click on $Button1, it shows a text in a TextBox and it shows in the main_form antoher 2 buttons, $OKButton16 and $CancelButton. This is as user confirmation to definitively run the invoke-command under $OKButton16.add_Click.

The problem is that each time I click on $Button1 and then on $OKButton16, the invoke-command and the rest of code under $OKButton16.add_Click is run as many times you have clicked.

For example, the second time I click on $Button1 and then on $OKButton16, the code is run 2 times in a row.

I need a way to just run the script 1 time when I click on $OKButton16.

Sorry if I not explain the problem very well, but English is not my native language.

Thank you in advance

I need a way to just run the script 1 time when I click on $OKButton16.

I have tried to run a $OKButton16.remove_Click after $Button1.Enabled = $True, but it is not working, maybe I do something wrong.

As well I have tried to delete the $OKButton16 click event, but I think that I have not clear how to do it.

Comment: Every time `$OKButton16.add_Click({<scriptblock>})` is ran, it adds another copy of the scriptblock to $OKButton16.  Every time $OKButton16 is clicked, it runs all the copies of the scriptblocks.

Comment: And how can I delete each copy of the scriptblock after each click?

Comment: And as well this only occurrs when I do another cycle clicking on $Button1. I mean, If I don't remove the $OKButton16 after click in It, and when It finished I click again, It works correctly running the code 1 time. It seems it is occurrs because $OKButton16.add_click is embedded inside $Button1.add_click. Makes sense? Thanks for your response

Comment: Also, instead of adding / removing the buttons you can set their ```Visible``` property to true / false - that way you can initialise them once when you create the form. The ```$OKButton16.add_Click``` can be moved to the form setup code as well then…

Comment: Fantastic idea @mclayton!!
I just tried and it works perfectly. Putting the $OKButton16.add_Click in the main code outside from $Button1.add_Click is working correctly. Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

**The 2 code examples below offer 4 methods of enabling and disabling a button.**

This example is an expanded version of mclayton's idea of changing the `Visible` property, except it is initially configured to change the `Enabled` property.

If you prefer to use `Visible`, uncomment the 3 lines ending in `# Visible` and comment out the 3 lines ending in `# Enabled`.

```
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = [Form]@{
    Text = "Button Events"
    ClientSize  = "300,70"
    FormBorderStyle = 'FixedSingle'
    MaximizeBox = $false
    StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    TopMost = $true
}

$BtnBClick = {
    if($form.Text -eq 'Yes') {
        $form.Text = 'No'
    }
    else {
        $form.Text = 'Yes'
    }
}

$EB = 'Enable Button'
$DB = 'Disable Button'
$WidthA = 90
$ButtonA = [Button]@{
    Location = "12, 12"
    Size = "$WidthA, 20"
    Text = $EB
}
$form.Controls.Add($ButtonA)

$WidthB = 90
$ButtonB = [Button]@{
    Location = "$($form.ClientSize.Width - ($WidthB + 12) ), 12"
    Size = "$WidthB, 20"
    Text = "Change Title"
    Enabled = $false                    # Enabled
    #Visible = $false                   # Visible
}
$form.Controls.Add($ButtonB)
$ButtonB.add_Click($BtnBClick)


$ButtonA.add_Click({
    if($ButtonA.Text -eq $EB) {
        $ButtonA.Text = $DB
        $ButtonB.Enabled = $true        # Enabled
        #$ButtonB.Visible = $true       # Visible
    }
    else {
        $ButtonA.Text = $EB
        $ButtonB.Enabled = $false       # Enabled
        #$ButtonB.Visible = $false      # Visible
    }
})

$null = $form.ShowDialog()
```

This example is configured to add or remove the event handler from the button - the button's appearance will not change, but, when the event handler is removed, it will not function.  If you wish to add or remove the button from the form, uncomment the 3 lines ending in `# Add/Remove Button` and comment out the 3 lines ending in `# Add/Remove Event`.

```
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$form = [Form]@{
    Text = "Button Events"
    ClientSize  = "300,70"
    FormBorderStyle = 'FixedSingle'
    MaximizeBox = $false
    StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    TopMost = $true
}

$BtnBClick = {
    if($form.Text -eq 'Yes') {
        $form.Text = 'No'
    }
    else {
        $form.Text = 'Yes'
    }
}

$EB = 'Enable Button'
$DB = 'Disable Button'
$WidthA = 90
$ButtonA = [Button]@{
    Location = "12, 12"
    Size = "$WidthA, 20"
    Text = $EB
}
$form.Controls.Add($ButtonA)

$WidthB = 90
$ButtonB = [Button]@{
    Location = "$($form.ClientSize.Width - ($WidthB + 12) ), 12"
    Size = "$WidthB, 20"
    Text = "Change Title"
    Enabled = $true
}
$form.Controls.Add($ButtonB)                # Add/Remove Event
#$ButtonB.add_Click($BtnBClick)             # Add/Remove Button

$ButtonA.add_Click({
    if($ButtonA.Text -eq $EB) {
        $ButtonA.Text = $DB
        $ButtonB.add_Click($BtnBClick)      # Add/Remove Event
        #$form.Controls.Add($ButtonB)       # Add/Remove Button
    }
    else {
        $ButtonA.Text = $EB
        $ButtonB.remove_Click($BtnBClick)   # Add/Remove Event
        #$form.Controls.Remove($ButtonB)    # Add/Remove Button
    }
})

$null = $form.ShowDialog()
```

**Special note concerning adding and removing of the event handler: Assigning the event handler to a variable, in this case $BtnBClick, and using that same variable for both the add and remove of the event handler is the only way I know to do this.
Someone with more years experience working with PowerShell might know of other methods.**